# Budget monitor smaller than 20" for gaming

Tags: gaming, monitors

The monitor must have those characteristics:

- FullHD (1920 × 1080 pixel, 1080p)
- Flicker-free/Flicker safe
- 75-120 Hz
- Response time 1-5ms
- AMD Freesync
- IPS
- Smaller than 20"
- 16:9 aspect ratio

*Built in speakers are not required*

Unfortunately I couldn't find anything like that on the internet, even though I've searched everywhere. Can anyone recommend me any monitor with this characteristics?

Comment: [According to AMD's Freesync monitor search tool](https://www.amd.com/en/products/freesync-monitors) the smallest monitor that supports Radeon FreeSync is 22" (rounded up) which makes your constraints impossible to meet at this time. [This is probably the closet monitor at 21.5".](https://www.amazon.it/AOC-G2260VWQ6-Monitor-1920x1080-Speaker/dp/B0158L13M4)